# "speak the Russian language" or "speak Russian language " or "speak Russian"?

Tags: grammar, articles

Tell me please what is the most grammatically correct and natural way to say the following.

> (**A**) The people in Russia mostly speak **the Russian** **language**.
>   (**B**) The people in Russia mostly speak **Russian language**.
>   (**C**) The people in Russia mostly speak **Russian**.

I feel that the second variant without the definite article in this context is incorrect, I am not sure though.

Comment: The most grammatically correct one and the natural way, as mentioned in the question, would be to say *'....mostly speak Russian'.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. It's either of the two: **they only speak the Russian language** or **they only speak Russian**. Generally speaking, the second option is grammatically incorrect. You can think of *Russian* as a short form of *the Russian language*.

*Language* when used as a mass noun (without an article, that is) means *the spoken or written method of human communication*. It's visual if we're talking about the written word and aural if we're talking about the spoken word. Here's a simple sentence as an example:

> **Human language** is what we humans use to communicate with each other.

To help you make better sense out of this, think of how it works with the word *sound*. *A sound* (or *the sound* if you're referring to a specific sound) is a particular type of sound that you can make, e.g.: a creaking sound, a screeching sound, a growling sound etc. *Sound* without an article refers to vibrations that travel through the air or another medium and can be heard when they reach a person's or animal's ear. And here's another sentence as an example:

> **Sound** is the basis for human language. Without **sound**, there would be no human language as we know it.